# Woking out directions from forces on a 2D plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, classical-mechanics

Assume P is a 2D object on a 2D plane. If there are N forces of equal strength pulling P in a particular direction, how can I calculate which direction P will move in?

Obviously, if there is only one N, P will move in that direction. If all the Ns are equally spaced out around P, P will not move at all, but when I use this, the Ns will be randomly placed around P.

Bonus points to anyone that can give a solution that takes into account the strengths of the Ns.

(Am I being clear enough? I'm a bit of a newbie at this.)

I really do not know how to tag this, so please retag it of you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to resolve each force into $x$ and $y$ coordinates, add up all the forces in the $x$ direction, add up all the forces in the $y$ direction.  This gives the $x,y$ coordinates of the resultant force.